# What's the difference between "intervene" and "interfere"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *intervene* and *interfere*? I think some example would really be helpful here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you can, of course, look up the definitions for [intervene](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intervene) and [interfere](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interfere?show=0&t=1290845894), but if you need more than that...

When someone intervenes, they are generally coming in between two parties who are in conflict in some manner. By intervening, they help attempt to resolve the conflict between the two parties. So, for instance, you could have two people arguing, and someone else intervenes to try and stop the argument. They are helping, and it has a positive connotation.

On the other hand, when someone interferes, they're just getting in the way. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with two parties in conflict or even more than one party at all. Someone who interferes is getting in the way of someone else doing something. So, if I'm trying to get my work done, and you interfere, you're stopping me (or at least impeding me) from getting my work done. There's nothing positive about it. It's entirely negative.

Comment: Thank You, Jonathan!!! That's exactly what I needed - not only definitions from a dictionary, but the real comparison of two words and fetching the difference.

Answer (score 11):

*Intervene* has a positive connotation, while *interfere* has a more negative one. To *interfere* can mean *to restrain*, while *intervene* more leans towards *to come between* (lat. *inter*: between, *venire*: come), to engage. *Interfere* comes from lat. *fere*: to do.

One could say that interfere means to *go between* to do something, to restrain, disrupt, disturb with a focus on the doing part, the action that is done, while *intervene* means to *come between* to prevent, focusing on the motion part of coming between.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand and what I learned, summarized.

To Interfere is for someone or for a party to make his way to another person or other party's business or doing, or an act of making an edge for intrusion onto someone or some people's affairs or situation; make a mark over a person or situation.

To Intervene is to mediate or go in between parties, with a positive purpose of calming or making a situation better, or arrive at a solution, usually due to conflicts or situation  between parties.

Comment: Do you have any references to support that?